# Git Revision Expression

Tags: git, user-interface

I am trying to get started with git, and am using Git GUI. I have my pre-written code, created a repo in it's directory, but cannot push, as there are no branches. When I try to make one, it wants a "Revision Expression". I don't know what that is.

Comment: Have you done git init? Also I found the best way to learn was to use Git Bash and read Pro Git

Comment: Also master should exist by default and if you are trying to push you must have an origin/master etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You push to a remote repository.

What you want to do is `git add` and than `git commit`.

I suggest, you work yourself through the [`git school`](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1) to learn the basics.